# Are functional components that are class properties an anti-pattern in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, anti-patterns

There's a few places in an existing codebase that I work on that has a functional component as a class property on a React component to avoid having to pass state, props, and callbacks to a child component. An example is below, or in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-sky-wpjpb?file=/src/App.js).

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  ClassPropComponent = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div>Count is {this.state.counter}</div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              counter: this.state.counter + 1
            });
          }}
        >
          +
        </button>
      </>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <this.ClassPropComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is there anything inherently wrong with this pattern?

1. I believe that this would create a new instance of the `ClassPropComponent` for every instance of `App`. Though, I imagine since it's a functional component, there wouldn't be much additional overhead, if any.
2. Are there any dangers or gotchas as far as using hooks in the `ClassPropComponent`? It doesn't break any of the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) as far as I can tell.
3. Is there any advantage to this pattern over just a function on the class that returns some JSX? It seems that the only difference is that it'd be used as a component instead of a function call (eg. `<this.ClassPropComponent />` vs `this.renderComponent()`)?

*(next section is partially off-topic, and may be better suited for another question)*

Another interesting edge-case occurs when we have a component that is a class property render another component that is a class property. Our codebase is in Typescript, and if we use `ts-loader` then run the result through babel, everything works fine. If we use `@babel/preset-typescript` and `@babel/preset-react`(with the @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties), `this` is undefined in the class prop component rendered by another class prop component.